# detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:

Tags: objective-c

This method `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`will call a method that is without any arguments.But i have to start the thread that reecives a single argument upon execution.How to accomplish this `using threads`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/detachNewThreadSelector%3atoTarget%3awithObject%3a) again. The method is *supposed* to take one argument, the value of which is specified as the `withObject:` portion of the message.